# Unable to update column of a table in Oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to update two tables in Oracle database.The first try/catch part works fine, however, the second one does not update penalty_fine column, although I have used the same code. The query works fine on Toad. I tried to merge them into one try/catch by merging sql queries, but it did not work on the second table.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
try
{

    OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand();

    command2.CommandText = "Update t_payment set amount = :amount + (select amount from t_payment where penalty_order_id = (select id from t_penalty_order where protokol_no = :invoiceNumber)) where penalty_order_id = (select id from t_penalty_order where protokol_no = :invoiceNumber)";

    command2.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(@"amount", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(request.amount);
    command2.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(@"invoiceNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255)).Value = request.invoiceNumber;

    command2.Connection = connection;

    command2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;


    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    completePayment.code = 111;
    completePayment.message = e.Message;
    completePayment.transactionNumber = null;
}




try
{

    OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand();

    command2.CommandText = "Update t_penalty_order set penalty_fine = 10 where protokol_no = :invoiceNumber";


    command2.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(@"invoiceNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255)).Value = request.invoiceNumber;

    command2.Connection = connection;

    command2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;


    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    completePayment.code = 111;
    completePayment.message = e.Message;
    completePayment.transactionNumber = null;
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't. It simply does not update penalty_fine in the table t_penalty_order

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the remote server and it started working. Thank you